# what's the purpose of BufferedOutputStream?

Tags: java

I am wondering the purpose of BufferedOutputStream, performance gain when using it?

Comment: It worth noting that if you are already writing large chunks of data e.g. 8K or more, it may harm performance slightly (as would wrapping a BufferedOutputStream around a BufferedOutputStream)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the line from [API of BufferedOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html):

> The class implements a buffered output stream. By setting up such an output stream, an application can write bytes to the underlying output stream **without** necessarily causing a call to the underlying system for each byte written.

It can do most of operations within the buffer, and without a call to the underlying system.

For example, consider writing to file: without buffer, it has to make a system call for every single byte, which is obviously slow.

Comment: "without buffer, it has to access the hard disk for every single byte" that statement is likely false

Comment: @Raedwald im not so sure about that. From java api "The write method of OutputStream calls the write method of one argument on each of the bytes to be written out. Subclasses are encouraged to override this method and provide a more efficient implementation."

Comment: Calling a single byte output method does not cause a single disk write. The operating system will buffer writes itself.

Comment: @Raedwald , It doesn't "have" to acces, but it "could".

Comment: The exact purpose of java buffered output stream isn't to reduce the pressure of disk I/O, but rather to reduce the frequency of calling the write() syscall which is very costly. Because of the existence of OS page cache, there is no big difference on performance by using buffered output stream or not.

Answer (score 9):

As its name suggests, `BufferOutputStream` has an internal buffer (`byte[]`) to which contents of individual small writes are first copied. They are written to the underlying `OutputStream` when buffer is full, or the stream is flushed, or the stream is closed.
This can make a big difference if there is a (relatively large) fixed overhead for each  write operation to the underlying `OutputStream`, as is the case for `FileOutputStream` (which must make an operating system call) and many compressed streams.

At the same time, many stream-based libraries use their own buffering (like XML and JSON writers), and use of `BufferedOutputStream` provides no benefit. But its own overhead is relatively low so there isn't much risk.

Answer (score 3):

BufferedOutputStream provides output data buffering which increases efficiency by storing values to be written in a buffer and actually writing them out when the buffer fills or when the flush() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Java BufferedOutputStream class is used for buffering an output stream. It internally uses buffer to store data. It adds more efficiency than to write data directly into a stream. So, it makes the performance fast.