# What is the benefit of a BufferedOutputStream in java? Doesn't every OutputStream have a buffer?

Tags: java, stream, buffer, outputstream

my question is in some way similar to this one:
[what's the purpose of BufferedOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561815/whats-the-purpose-of-bufferedoutputstream)
I have read the answers there, but there is still one thing I do not really understand:
So in Java a BufferedOutputStream has an internal buffer. And if this buffer is full or flush() is called, it writes the data to the underlying OutputStream (the one that was passed to the BufferedOutputStream's constructor).
So far ok. But for me it looks, as if in fact any OutputStream would have such a buffer - as the base class OutputStream has a method flush(). The description of this method sais: "Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out."
So ... if all OutputStreams have a buffer, what is the benefit of a BufferedOutputStream then?
Probably I am misunderstanding something ... can you please help me?

Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: 'The description of this method sais: "Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out'. Read on. Your question is based on a false assumption.

Comment: Not every `OutputStream` has an internal buffer, but still will effectively have a buffer when you call `write` with a sufficiently large array argument. In this regard, `BufferedOutputStream` is indeed obsolete and an overused feature. More than often, it’s better to fix the code that does too many small writes instead of working around the problem by using a `BufferedOutputStream`. For code using reasonable buffer sizes, additionally using a `BufferedOutputStream` can even *degrade* performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) is abstract. Meaning it defines the interface and some common behavior of all output streams. You cannot instantiate `OutputStream` instance.

The documentation clearly states that

> The flush method of OutputStream does nothing.

It is up to the concrete implementation to determine whether or not it uses a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

OutputStream has no buffer, you can check source code. BufferedOutputStream has its own buffer, its flush() writes bytes from own buffer to OS then flushes OS buffer. Why using BufferedOutputStream is more efficient - because  OutputStream.write may call OS each time, which is expensive operation, and BufferedOutputStream.write puts bytes to buffer and calls OS only when buffer is full or on flush

Comment: Its `flush()` does *nothing*. No 'flushes OS buffer' about it.

Comment: 'Flushes OS buffer' how?